# Best bets for fresh fish for sushi/sashimi?

Tags: fish, sushi

Assuming a big city on the Easter Seaboard in the U.S. with a fresh fish market, what would you say are the best bets for sushi-grade freshness when it comes to types of fish?

What I have done before is buy a tuna steak and smell it before and also make sure it doesn't have the rainbowy sheen on the surface -- never got sick.  Do you know of other types of fish that are typically fresh enough at fish markets that you could use to make sushi?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the fish market in question, any fish could be left lying about at the harbor before it's sold.

I know when I was in Sydney they sold sashimi grade eel, squid, octopus, mackerel and tuna.